# Using cmake, how to link an object file built by an external_project statement into another library?

Tags: cmake

In our project, we want to use a third-party library (A) which is built using autotools and which generates an object file (B) which we need @ link time of one of our libraries (C).

```
external_project(
    A
    ...
)
set_source_files_properties(B PROPERTIES DEPEND A)
add_library(C ... A)
add_dependency(C B)
```

I had the impression that this should do the trick, but the cmake command fails by stating that it cannot find file A during the check for add_library.

Any fixes or alternative solutions would be greatly appreciated! (changing the third-party library is not an option)
thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few issues here:

- `external_project` should be [`ExternalProject_Add`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#module%3aExternalProject)
- Source files have no property called `DEPEND` available - the `set_source_files_properties` command has no effect here.  (Here are the [properties available on source files](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#section_PropertiesonSourceFiles))
- [`add_library`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command%3aadd_library) expects a list of source files to be passed, not another CMake target (which `A` is)
- `add_dependency` should be [`add_dependencies`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command%3aadd_dependencies)

Apart from those 4 lines it's all OK :-)

So the issue is going to be that you want to include the object file `B` in the `add_library` call, but it's not going to be available at configure-time (when CMake is invoked), only at build time.

I think you're going to have to do something like:

```
ExternalProject_Add(
    A
    ...
)

set_source_files_properties(
    ${B} PROPERTIES
    EXTERNAL_OBJECT TRUE  # Identifies this as an object file
    GENERATED TRUE  # Avoids need for file to exist at configure-time
)

add_library(C ... ${B})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, perfect answer! (I did not intend to write effective cmake code, but maybe that would have been clearer ;) )

Comment: @RaulLuna In the original question, the OP has mentioned that there's an object file which he's called "B" - I'm assuming it's defined as a variable earlier in the CMakeLists.txt